# ReactiveList related searches

Tags: reactivesearch

I'm trying to figure out how I can ReactiveList to display a related searches feature on the results page. It seems that my es app on appbaseio keeps adding links EVEN after the page has sat idle for a few minutes, NO USER INTERACTION at all.

This is my code for the ReativeList component

```
<ReactiveList
  componentId="related-searches"
  pages={1}
  size={5}
  stream={false}
  showResultStats={false}
  react={{
    "and": ["SearchSensor"]
  }}
  onData={(res) => <a href="#" className="card-link"><li 
   className="list-inline-item">Link text</li></a>}
  />
```

I thought that pages, size and stream (and their settings) would stop the streaming (or whatever is causing it)?

Comment: Not sure about the 'adding of links', could you create a codesandbox demo, added answer for the related searches though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `defaultQuery` prop on `ReactiveList` to make it show some default results (or related searches in your case) [docs](https://opensource.appbase.io/reactive-manual/result-components/reactivelist.html#props). For example:

```
<ReactiveList
  ...
  defaultQuery={() => ({
    match: {
      authors: 'J.K. Rowling'
    }
  })}
/>
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/yp22l1o5lj)